# MRTK 2.4 - Save Spatial Mesh on Runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, spatial, mesh, hololens, mrtk

Right now I'm trying to save the spatial mesh on my hololens as an obj-file. My problem is that, when trying to open the obj-file e.g. in Blender (or 3D Viewer) I get an error that says `IndexError: List index out of range`. So I guess I'm giving my triangles the wrong index (in the last part of `MeshToString()`), but I don't know how to do it the right way.
**What works:** For example if I take only one mesh out of the first meshfilter and cut out `+ lastFaceIndex` in the `MeshToString()` it works fine. But thats only a part of my room. And I want the whole mesh from my room, so I have to go through all the mesh filters and get my mesh and then write them into an obj-file, but I dont know how to give the triangles the right index.
Also I noticed that if I download the mesh via device portal it has ~4.8MB, but the mesh I'm downloading via my unity application has only 1.4MB.
**My Setup:**
Unity 2019.3.14
MRTK 2.4
HoloLens 2nd Gen

**GetSpatialMesh():**

```
private void GetSpatialMesh()
{
    if (_observer == null)
        return;

    List<Mesh> meshes = new List<Mesh>();
    // Loop through all known Meshes
    foreach (SpatialAwarenessMeshObject meshObject in _observer.Meshes.Values)
        meshes.Add(meshObject.Filter.mesh);
    WriteMeshToFile("MyMesh.obj", meshes);
}
```

**WriteMeshToFile():**

```
public static void WriteMeshToFile(string fileName, IEnumerable<Mesh> meshes)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, fileName);
    using (var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
    {
        faceCount = 0;
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            int o = 0;
            foreach (Mesh mesh in meshes)
            {
                o++;
                writer.WriteLine("o Object." + o);
                writer.Write(MeshToString(mesh, faceCount));
                writer.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MeshToString():**

```
public static string MeshToString(Mesh m, int lastFaceIndex = 0)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Vector3 v in m.vertices)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("v {0} {1} {2}\n", v.x, v.y, v.z));
    }
    sb.Append("\n");
    foreach (Vector3 v in m.normals)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("vn {0} {1} {2}\n", v.x, v.y, v.z));
    }
    sb.Append("\n");
    foreach (Vector3 v in m.uv)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("vt {0} {1}\n", v.x, v.y));
    }
    for (int material = 0; material < m.subMeshCount; material++)
    {
        int[] triangles = m.GetTriangles(material);
        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3)
        {
            faceCount += 3;
            sb.Append(string.Format("f {0}/{0}/{0} {1}/{1}/{1} {2}/{2}/{2}\n",
                triangles[i] + 1 + lastFaceIndex, triangles[i + 1] + 1 + lastFaceIndex, triangles[i + 2] + 1 + lastFaceIndex));
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Solution:**
The scene understanding [sample project](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples) didnt work for me, so I just got the sdk via nuget manager in unity. I used the code from [SceneUnderstandingManager](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples/blob/master/Assets/SceneUnderstanding/Core/Understanding/Scripts/SceneUnderstandingManager.cs#L1154)(which is part of the sample project), referenced by Hernando-MSFT in his answer below.

Comment: Where on the Hololens does persistentDataPath() save to?

Comment: Windows Device Portal → File Explorer → Local App Data → YourApp → LocalState. This took like 2 seconds for me to google:
http://www.appzinside.com/2018/08/06/hololens-and-unity-tip-004-storing-and-retrieving-data-on-hololens-device-storage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the code you posted is based on [Legacy HoloToolkit](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/1676) but all support will now be with the newer [Scene understanding SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/scene-understanding-sdk). Since you are using HoloLens2, we recommend you using Scene understanding SDK to query a static version of the spatial mapping data and save a serialized scene bytes to disk.
After scanning the room, invoke [`SceneObserver.ComputeSerializedAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/scene-understanding-sdk#initialization-from-data-aka-the-pc-path) to serialize the scene as a byte array.

[Microsoft.MixedReality.SceneUnderstanding.Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples) is a Unity-based sample application that showcases Scene Understanding on HoloLens 2. And it shows up how to save any scene you've captured by saving the output of ComputeSerializedAsync to file: [Line1154](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples/blob/master/Assets/SceneUnderstanding/Core/Understanding/Scripts/SceneUnderstandingManager.cs#L1154)

Besides, the `SaveObjsToDiskAsync` function show how to save the Unity Objects from Scene Understanding as Obj files: [Line1206](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples/blob/master/Assets/SceneUnderstanding/Core/Understanding/Scripts/SceneUnderstandingManager.cs#L1206)

Comment: I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SceneUnderstanding-Samples), but I get only this kind of [errors](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/7948). The strange part is that they say its caused by switching between standalone to uwp and back. But I didnt switched back, I just switched to uwp. And the way to fix that error is also not working. 'CDiaz-MS' wrote 'This issue can be resolved by deleting the Dependencies folder after the switch back to Standalone'. I deleted all the stuff under 'Assets\Packages' and it didnt fix the issue.

Comment: That sample is targeted to Unity 2019.2.21f1 and I verified it worked well. And I have no the same Unity version installed on my PC, the higher version 2019.4.3f1 can correctly handle the upgrading job. Just give you a reference to narrow down this Unity issue

Comment: ok, I guess I'm too stupid for that. Tried version 2019.4 and it still gives me the same error. Here an [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/3sf5mn6). So I'm just gonna use the sdk

Comment: hey, I tried the example project on another computer and it worked well. Don't know why its not working on this one.

Comment: @Hernando - MSFT I have a general question about the spatial mesh from SU sdk and MRTK. Right now I'm extracting parts out of the spatial mesh, that gets shown by mrtk. And it works fine for me :)! Also I tried to extract some parts from the mesh which is shown by the SU sdk (`RenderWorldMesh = true; StartDisplay()`), but can't collide with the mesh, because it has no colliders on it. I understood that if I want to save the whole spatial mesh, I should use SU sdk, but what about extracting some parts out of the spatial mesh?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I know this is kind of old and that Perazim already solve his problem, but I also needed to transform hololens 2 Mesh into obj, so... maybe it can be useful to someone else in the future :), this is why I am puting out my solution.

Unfortunately I didn't manage to use the code with the scene understanding, as sujested by Hernando (Disclaimer it is my first attempt to program to Hololens, so.... I'm pretty sure it is my fault). When I try to call

> SceneBuffer serializedScene = SceneObserver.ComputeSerializedAsync(querySettings, 10.0f).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

I got an error, in fact my application just didn't work anymore!

What I did, and worked, was to create the obj "by hand", and the function that worked for me is the following:

```
    private void exportScene(String targetFileName)
    {
        var spatialAwarenessSystem = CoreServices.SpatialAwarenessSystem;
        spatialAwarenessSystem.SuspendObservers();

        var observer = CoreServices.GetSpatialAwarenessSystemDataProvider<IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessMeshObserver>();
        System.Text.StringBuilder objFileContent = new System.Text.StringBuilder(4096);
        objFileContent.Append("# Automatic export of Hololens 2 scanned mesh scan. \r\n\r\n");

        // Collects the spread objects
        foreach (SpatialAwarenessMeshObject meshObject in observer.Meshes.Values)
        {
            meshes.Add(meshObject.Filter);
        }

        int adjust = 1;
        MeshFilter[] mf = meshes.ToArray();
        int countVertex = 0;

        // for each object gets the vertexes normals and faces
        for (int i = 0; i < mf.Length; i++)
        {
            Mesh m = mf[i].sharedMesh;
            objFileContent.Append("o Object." + (i + 1) + "\r\n");
            
            // inverts x as the coordinates are different from the ones of regular obj
            foreach (Vector3 v in m.vertices)
            {
                float x = -v.x;
                float z = v.z;
                objFileContent.Append("v " + x.ToString("0.000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + v.y.ToString("0.000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + z.ToString("0.000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\r\n");
            }

            objFileContent.Append("\r\n\r\n");

            foreach (Vector3 n in m.normals)
            {
                float x = n.x;
                float z = n.z;
                objFileContent.Append("vn " + x.ToString("0.000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + n.y.ToString("0.000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + z.ToString("0.000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "\r\n");
            }
            objFileContent.Append("\r\n\r\n");

            // the count of the faces starts with 1 and is cumulative for 
            // all objects on the scene this is why it is add 
            // adjust + countVertex as the id of the vertexes
            for (int ti = 0; ti < m.triangles.Length; ti += 3)
            {
                objFileContent.Append("f " + (m.triangles[ti] + adjust + countVertex ) + "//" + (m.triangles[ti] + adjust + countVertex) + " " + (m.triangles[ti + 1] + adjust + countVertex) + "//" + (m.triangles[ti + 1] + adjust + countVertex) + " " + (m.triangles[ti + 2] + adjust + countVertex) + "//" + (m.triangles[ti + 2] + adjust + countVertex) + "\r\n");
            }
            objFileContent.Append("\r\n\r\n");
            countVertex += m.vertexCount;
      }
       // string objPath = Path.Combine(sceneFolderPath, sceneName + ".obj"); 
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(targetFileName))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(objFileContent.ToString());
        }
    }
```